# Copying a desired string from a text file in C

Tags: c, string, text, strstr

I have read all the text from a desired file and it is now stored in `buff`. I want to copy just the string content after identifier strings such as 'Title'.

Example file below:

```
"Title: I$_D$-V$_{DS}$ Characteristic Curves (Device 1)
MDate: 2016-03-01
XLabel: Drain voltage V$_{DS}$
YLabel: Drain current I$_D$
CLabel: V$_{GS}$
XUnit: V
... "
```

---

```
for(;;) {
    size_t n = fread(buff, 1 , DATAHOLD, inFile);

    subString = strstr( buff, "Title");

        if( subString != NULL) {   
            strcpy(graph1.title , (subString + 7));
            subString = NULL;
        }

       ....more if statements....

        if( n < DATAHOLD) {
            break;
        }
}
```

I understand that `strstr()` returns a pointer to location of the search string, I added `7` to get just the text that comes after the search string and this part works fine. The problem is `strcpy()` copies the rest of `buff` character array into `graph1.title`.
How to instruct `strcpy()` to only copy the text on the same line as the `substring` pointer? Using `strtok()` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [ChuckCottrill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2840714/chuckcottrill), it would be better if you read and process one line at a time.

Also since the file you are dealing with is a text file, you could be opening it in text mode.

```
FILE *fin = fopen("filename", "r");
```

Read a line with `fgets()` into a string `str`. It should be noted that `fgets()` will take the trailing `\n'` to `str`.

```
fgets(str, sizeof(str), fin);

char *substring;
if( (substring = strstr(str, "Title: ")) != NULL )
{
    strcpy(graph1.title, substring+strlen("Title: "));
}
```

At this point, `graph1.title` will have `I$_D$-V$_{DS}$ Characteristic Curves (Device 1)` in it.

Comment: fgets should have the first and last arguments switched. I like the idea, I'll try it out

Answer (score 1):

Read and process a single line at a time.

```
for( ; fgets(line,...); ) {
    do stuff on line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use another `strstr` to get the **position of the end of the line**,  and then use `strncpy` which is like `strcpy`, but accepts a *third argument*, the **number of chars to copy** of the input.